# Make input height increase when typing

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input element with a height of 10px and width of 100px. But if the user types in data that is longer than that width, the overflow is not shown. How do I make the input element's height increase when there is an overflow?
Is this achievable with css? If not, then Vanilla JS would be the preferred.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
```

CSS:

```
#input{
margin-left: 10px;
border-left: transparent;
border-right: transparent;
border-top: transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
width: 100px;
height: auto;
min-height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's doable, but it's a lot of work. You would need to capture the input on each keystroke and then using the exact same font and size as the input element, create an element on the page somewhere (or rather *off* the page so no one sees it) using the same content, measure its size and compare that to the input element's size, adjust if needed, then dispose of the other element again.

Personally, I would probably just use a `textarea` element. It'll have scrollbars if needed, and you can let users resize it if they want.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to update automatically and want to avoid scroll bar as in `textarea`. Try using `div` with `contenteditable="true"`. It will make validation a little difficult but will do the Job. Check out the Snippet:-

```css
div{
  padding:0.5em;
  background-color:pink;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Edit Me</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `textarea`, you can specify the number of rows that you want and if the user enters more than these rows then a scroll will be shown.

If you want to add the feature of auto grow then you need a little javascript to do it that actually calculate the height of the element based on its content on input event

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("test");
textArea.addEventListener("input", evt => {
    textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + "px";
});
```